# Unity: create 2D coliders over specific background tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, maps, 2d

Im trying to create a 2D TopDown(like Zelda or Pokemon) Game in Unity 5.3. I used Tiled (http://www.mapeditor.org) to create a map with sprites in layers (a green background to represent grass, a layer with trees, a layer with water, a layer with items... etc

Then I used Tiled2unity(http://www.seanba.com/tiled2unity) to import the map to the unity aplication. That create a folder with prefabs and create the map in a Empty Object with the map prefab.

Then I added a player, with animations, with a RigidBody. And tryed to add coliders to the tree layer. I want to create them over every tile in the tree layer. Could you guide me? I tryed to add a box colider to the prefab and in the objects in the prefab, but that creates a big unique colider.

In 1 hour I will post a photo and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is really simple:
In Tiled (map creator), you can add a new layer called "Collisions", where you can mark all the tiles you want colliders on, then import into Unity from Tiled using Tiled2Unity, disable the mesh render of the object created in unity with that new layer (to hide the colliders to players), and you can add a Collider2D component to the parent object which contains all the colliders.